# Powershell Active Directory (Operating System)

Tags: powershell, properties, active-directory, operating-system

How do I set the operating system to a value? Every time I run the following, the AD portion of 'Operating System' Tab is always missing.

```
 Import-Csv "C:\test.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    New-QADComputer -Name $_.FirstName `
    -ComputerName $_.FirstName `
    -OperatingSystem 'test' `
    -ParentContainer 'test/TheWorkstations/TestGroup'
    }
```

Comment: According to the [Wiki](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/New-QADComputer) there is no parameter for `OperatingSystem` in `New-QADComputer`

Comment: Do you know of any other alternative of how do i access that by using powershell scripting?

Comment: The computer updates its active directory object with that information. What are you trying to set the OS name?

Comment: im trying to set the name as 'testOS' for testing purposes

Comment: I don't think you can do that. If you want to set something you can query later consider using one of the custom attributes or description instead.

Comment: @Matt The attribute is writable, so it should be doable in principle. However, since the attribute is automatically populated, manually entered information might be overwritten at any point, so I simply wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers. If you really had you heart set on this i suppose you could specify `-IncludedProperties operatingSystem` and maybe use `-ObjectAttributes @{operatingSystem='test'}`. I have never used the quest cmdlets so I apologize if this leads you astray.

Answer (score 1):

What about using classic active directory powershell module(not New-QADComputer)? It works this way.

```
New-ADComputer 'testcomputer' -OperatingSystem 'test'
```